# magento setTemplate is not working in ubuntu

Tags: magento, ubuntu-12.04

I have created my custom module and its working fine in Windows, but on ubuntu `setTemplate()` function is not rendering template. I am displaying this template with this code

```
class Group_GroupPrice_Block_Adminhtml_Tabs_Tabid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('GroupPrice/setgroupprice.phtml');
    }
}
```

My packege name is Group and package is GroupPrice.

I have placed template file inside `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/groupprice/groupprice.phtml`

Comment: Chack the case of template path. And remove GroupPrice from the path

Comment: thanks @DushyantJoshi I can not remove GroupPrice because its a template folder and I am using this template inside product edit page

Comment: But your given path is template/groupprice.phtml. so no need to add GroupPrice there

Comment: It should be $block->setTemplate('PATH/RELATIVE/TO/TEMPLATE/*.phtml');

Comment: is app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/groupprice.phtml path correct?

Comment: @DushyantJoshi corrected path is app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/groupprice/groupprice.phtml but still not working

Comment: have u changed GroupPrice to groupprice in $this->setTemplate('GroupPrice/setgroupprice.phtml');?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49651/discussion-between-dushyant-joshi-and-ashwani-panwar)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu have case-sensitive file system and Windows not. I'm sure 'GroupPrice/setgroupprice.phtml' is not real path.

Looks like you have to use `$this->setTemplate('groupprice.phtml');`
If your template file is really there.

Comment: Thanks @exec , I have changed path 'groupprice/setgroupprice.phtml' for template folder groupprice but its not working .

Comment: if your code is working at Windows then problem is in file or directory names that can contain uppercase letters. Make sure your file and folder names **exactly** matches path you are calling

Answer (score 1):

When your template is:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/groupprice.phtml
```

you should use:

```
$this->setTemplate('groupprice.phtml');
```

No need to add package name here!

Comment: if this is not working your file is not in: app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/groupprice.phtml

Comment: if i put file to this location then got this error Invalid method Group_GroupPrice_Block_Adminhtml_Tabs_Tabid::showBlockPath(Array
(
    [0] => 
)
)

Comment: ok i have changed path and it is app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/groupprice/groupprice.phtml and method is $this->setTemplate('groupprice/groupprice.phtml'); and its not working, please let me know what I can do.

Comment: is your block rendered? Do a Mage::log("HERE") in your block class constructor and check if the block is actually instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

check your config.xml, in that your blocks part, is it properly defined. And if possible paste your code here

`<global>
    <blocks>
        <module_name>
             <class>Namespace_Modulename_Block</class>
        </module_name>
    </blocks>

</global>`

Comment: `<blocks> 
<groupprice> <class>Group_GroupPrice_Block</class> </groupprice> </blocks>`
**paste this code in your modules config.xml - under globals node**